# How do I display a carousel using Products.Carousel on my custom page template?

Tags: plone

I have a custom page template for my home page.

It does not display the carousel.

The template is as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
  xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
  xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
  xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
  lang="en"
  metal:use-macro="context/main_template/macros/master"
  i18n:domain="plone">
<body>
<metal:content-core fill-slot="content-core">
    Hello
</metal:content-core>
</body>
</html>
```

The configure.zcml snippet looks like this:

```
<browser:page
  for="Products.CMFPlone.browser.interfaces.INavigationRoot"
  name="homepage"
  template="homepage.pt"
  layer=".interfaces.IThemeSpecific"
  permission="zope2.View"
/>
```

I tried:

```
<tal:block tal:replace="structure here/carousel/@@banner-base" />
```

but get an AttributeError for banner-base.

Comment: Do I get you right: You have activated a carousel to a folder, it works as expected, but not when calling your template in that context? Or is it, you'd rather like to have a customized carousel? That's documented here: http://plone.org/products/carousel/#customizing-carousel    The more detailed you describe your use-case, the better we can help :-)

Comment: The 1st case. It works when i traverse to the folder. Not when I traverse to my template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view has to be satisfy the is_view_template criterion as enforced by the update() method of the Carousel viewlet.

To do this simply use the setLayout() of the folder.

Answer (score 2):

The correct context cannot be found, if a default-page is set to the folder or siteroot, like "front-page" is by default.

To resolve that, change its view to yours or any other view, which isn't a content-item, like 'Summary view' f.e.